# UITableView Grouping Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I looked through apple documentation and have not seen how to group cells. Is there a delegate method for that or do you set which group to put cells in in the cellForRow method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableView` has `section`s and `row`s. A `section` may contain any number of `row`s. I believe this is what you're after.

`UITableViewStylePlain` and `UITableViewStyleGrouped` are the two `style` choices, but either can be used no matter the number of sections or rows within each section.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that sections were groups.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean sections ?

If you

```
return section = 2 // it will create two groups (or) two sections.
```